# How to save IF condition as Boolean Variable?

Tags: excel, vba

The logic on my code depends on the user who is running the macro. 
e.g. if username is “abc” or “def” do something and if not do something other. 
That why I use the same lengthy code of If conditions many times. 
Is there any way to save IF condition as `Boolean Variable` ? 
Appreciate for any useful comments and answers.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
 
Sub Run_Depends_on_Username()
     If UserName = "ABC" Or UserName = "DEF" Or UserName = "XYZ" Then
       'Code
     End If
End Sub
```

And this is the function to get username

```
Function UserName() As String
  UserName = Environ("username")
End Function
```

Comment: Then, you should create a `Public` variable `boolAccepted as Boolean` on top of a standard module (in the declarations area) and simply use the function only once as: `If UserName = "ABC" Or UserName = "DEF" Or UserName = "XYZ" Then boolAccepted = true`. Then, simple use it as: `If boolAccepted Then...` But, in case of a VBA error, the boolean variable value may disappear. So it would be good to place the first code in some events to frequently update its value.

Comment: @FaneDuru , although it works, But I accepted answer by "FunThomas" as it   is a function.

Comment: I do not have a problem with that. I would also prefer that solution. I thought about a function after I mentioned about the possibility to loose the value, but too lazy to write about that, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, you can assign the result of a boolean expression directly to a variable, eg

```
Dim isAllowed as boolean
isAllowed = (UserName = "ABC" Or UserName = "DEF" Or UserName = "XYZ" )

' Use it:
if isAllowed Then
```

Alternative is to create a simple function

```
Function isAllowed() As Boolean
     isAllowed = (UserName = "ABC" Or UserName = "DEF" Or UserName = "XYZ")
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Not only does it work, it is also a very good idea, as you can see in the following screenshot (the watch-window shows the current values of the boolean variables):

[image]

Hereby the source code:

```
Sub Run_Depends_on_Username()
Dim Username As String
Dim b_ABC, b_DEF, b_XYZ As Boolean

Username = "DEF"

b_ABC = (Username = "ABC")
b_DEF = (Username = "DEF")
b_XYZ = (Username = "XYZ")


     If b_ABC Or b_DEF Or b_XYZ Then
        Range("A1").Value = "Yes"
     End If
End Sub
```